# Change timestamp on bitbucket

Tags: bitbucket, git-bash, bitbucket-server

I have made a file and add it  on 08 Jul 2019 14:00:00 +0000
but I wanted to show in Bitbucket repository this timestamp: Mon, 08 Jul 2019 11:42:00 +0000.
so I did:
  $ git commit -m"try444" --date="Mon, 08 Jul 2019 11:42:00 +0000"
then after the push the Bitbucket still show:08 Jul 2019 14:00:00 +0000

How to change the hour in Bitbucket server??

I have made a file and add it  on 08 Jul 2019 14:00:00 +0000
but I wanted to show in Bitbucket repository this timestamp: Mon, 08 Jul 2019 11:42:00 +0000.
so I did:
  $ git commit -m"try444" --date="Mon, 08 Jul 2019 11:42:00 +0000"

$ git commit -m"try444" --date="Mon, 08 Jul 2019 11:42:00 +0000"

Bitbucket still show:08 Jul 2019 14:00:00 +0000

Comment: did you try to add `GIT_COMMITTER_DATE`?



`GIT_COMMITTER_DATE="Mon, 08 Jul 2019 11:42:00 +0000" git commit --amend --no-edit --date "Mon, 08 Jul 2019 11:42:00 +0000"`

Comment: yes, didnt work.

Comment: the entier problem is in bitbucket and not in git.